# Area Of A Polygon In WinRT XAML C#

Tags: polygon, winrt-xaml, area

I need to determine the area of a Polygon object that's been drawn on a Canvas in a Windows Store App (WinRT) in XAML/C#.  It looks like they stripped the Geometry.GetArea() from the WinRT libraries, so I unfortunately can't use that.  Since this polygon is irregularly shaped, with a dynamic list of points, I can't use any static formulas.  Are there any libraries or 3rd-party extensions that I can use in WinRT to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  This method will take a Polygon object and give the area.

```
double GetPolygonArea(Polygon poly)
    {
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        foreach (Point p in poly.Points)
        {
            points.Add(p);
        }
        points.Add(poly.Points[0]);
        double xTotal = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < points.Count - 1; x++)
        {
            xTotal += ((points[x].X) * (points[x + 1].Y));
        }
        double yTotal = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < points.Count - 1; y++)
        {
            yTotal += ((points[y].Y) * (points[y + 1].X));
        }
        return Math.Abs((xTotal - yTotal) / 2);
    }
```